# Stack Mate - Explore your StackExchange accounts and get notified about unread messages and notifications on Windows Phone

Tags: app, windows-phone

### About

Stack Mate is a simple Windows Phone app which pulls in your StackExchange account details and keeps you up to date with any activity on the site. This application was not created to browse questions, answers, users, etc but rather to give you a central hub for your accounts.

- View your StackExchange messages, notifications and explore each of your accounts
- Periodic checks for new messages, notifications and reputation changes
- Pin a live tile for each of your accounts to have it update with your most recent information (reputation gained, unread message count, etc)
- Tap on a message or reputation change to jump straight to the related question/answer/comment.

[image: menu]
[image: overview]
[image]
[image]

### Platforms

- Windows Phone 7.5 (compatible with Windows Phone 8)

### Download

It's free! No ads. Just for fun.

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/stack-mate/bab7c62e-859e-4566-a67d-3b0e00a120ac

### Versions

- 1.4 (April 2014) - the app will no longer notify you that you have new messages/notifications more than once per message/notification. This behaviour was previously intended due to Windows Phone 7 missing any kind of central notification store, so it would be easy to miss a notification and you would never know it had occurred. Now with the action centre in Windows Phone 8, this is no required.
- 1.3 (March 2014) - previously for inbox messages and notifications to be marked as unread you had to log into StackExchange and select each item to mark it as read. This meant the app could be alerting you about inbox messages and notifications multiple times until you've read them on StackExchange, even though you've already read them in the app. Now you will only be alerted if they are unread on StackExchange and occurred after you last looked at the inbox message or notification screen within Stack Mate.
- 1.2 (March 2014) - site names with special characters were displaying the html encoded equivalent
- 1.1 (June 2013) - added the ability to order your sites and fixed the text for toast notifications
- 1.0 (December 2013) - release

### Credit

- Silverlight for Windows phone toolkit
- JSON.net
- MVVM light
- amCharts
- Html5 agility pack
- SharpZipLib-WP7

Comment: Nice app! Glad to not be the only bum who uses the new Windows Phone on stackoverflow. Would be nice if the My Sites tab sorted sites by rep. Looks like it's sorted by order of when I became a user of the site.

Comment: @PeterTurner Thanks Peter. Your wish is my command! I've submitted an update with an option to order the sites (so either reputation or a-z). I think the API sorts them by "site popularity" by default. Nice to see others getting some benefit out of it anyway! I really like Windows Phone! .NET ftw!

Comment: Nice, although still slightly unstable on WP7.8 - I had two crashes and one garbled Settings screen after 10 minutes playing around with it. Would it be possible to have my favourite tags placed somwehere, easily accessible?

Comment: @JensG Thanks for the feedback. I'm using 7.8 and haven't had any problems but will keep an eye on it. So far the app is based around viewing reputation and notifying you when actions occur on StackExchange and purposely not around viewing questions/answers/tags/users on each site but I'll see what I can do. If you have any other suggestions please leave them here also!

Comment: @spencerooni  I have sent a mail before anyways, it kicks me out in WP8.1 latest version do something about that.

Comment: @IlayaRajaS I got your mail. I didn't reply as I thought it was a bit rude. "Fix it", "low functionality" and now "do something about that". It's free, man. I'll have a look at the crash logs when I get some time. I use it every day and have no problem, so if crash logs don't tell me anything it will be hard to identity your problem. For now, try re-install.

Comment: @Spencer sorry about that my bad its not like I want to do any harm to you or be rude just frustrated by the app kicking me out. Again sorry about that now I feel bad.

Comment: Just a good suggestion why don't you post the same description in this on the store page as the description in the store page sounds serious but this is more pleasing add more words which sounds fun!(like free no ads use it for fun)that way you might get more downloads.

Comment: @IlayaRajaS Could you try the app again? I could reproduce your problem earlier today (error loading accounts/notifications/etc), but when I got to a computer to try to debug, everything started working. Potentially, something is occurring periodically with the StackExchange API.

Comment: Yeah I got that msg too I don't know but after a few soft resets its working fine(the earlier problem of kicking me out ) .say, this was intended by you for personal use is that so?

Comment: @IlayaRajaS Yes, I created it for personal use. I wanted notifications for Stack Overflow.

Comment: So far,probably one of best app for SE access via WM phones. Thanks!!!

Comment: I installed the app yesterday and I always get "Error loading notifications". Any idea why?

Comment: And could you make it possible to go from a pinned account tile to the app home screen? Thanks :)

Comment: @Stijn - maybe there is a problem deserialzing the json, like a new notification type. It works ok for my notifications. I can help if you're willing to send me the json you get when you use "https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-notifications", maybe put it on a GitHub gist and link here? Yep, I will make it possible to go from account screen to home screen.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/stijnherreman/cd16f97fd0647de2db9d

Comment: @Stijn Thanks for that. I've submitted an update. Should be available soon. A new notification type was added to the API so the deserializing was failing.